# Lexical Editor State not keeping HTML styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lexicaljs

I have taken the lexical editor state and converted to an HTML string. I am then setting that string to my component state, then using it to set the editor state in a sample display editor. However, when I parse from the HTML string back to lexical editor state, it seems to be removing any style tags off of html string. For example, I created a plugin that turns the text red. When I log out / examine the HTML string in state, I see this value:

`'<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: red; white-space: pre-wrap;">test</span></p>'`

As you can see, the color plugin I created is adding a style tag with the 'color: red;' styling. However, when I convert back in my display editor, it appears that the style tag is being left out. Here is my UpdateState plugin from the display editor:

```
function UpdateState({ currentEditorState }: any) {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in use effect: ", currentEditorState);
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(currentEditorState, "text/html");
    editor.update(() => {
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      console.log(nodes);
      const root = $getRoot();
      root.clear();
      root.append(...nodes);
    });
  }, [currentEditorState, editor]);
  return null;
}
```

The odd thing is that when I print out 'currentEditorState' it still has the style tag (also if I print out the dom, it has the style tag as well). However, after running the generateNodesFromDom, it appears that the style tag is being removed from the dom / lexical root node. Any ideas why this is happening, and what I can do to maintain the style tag and keep the appropriate styling?